# Importing android gradle project into eclipse

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I need to import this library project into my eclipse. While i am trying to use this project it have some error. Can you help me on this.  https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider

Comment: so what issue on importing it? any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically there are some changes to be done to eclipse project before importing it to eclipse like `src` folder.

The project you posted may contains many error since it have two more android project dependency.
I tired to convert above project with its dependency :

Checkout [Complete Source Code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lmr19rpq86xon15/New%20folder%20%282%29.rar)

There is one more project lib u need to add [LIB](https://github.com/square/picasso)

Answer (score 1):

That project is created for use with Gradle for Android. Eclipse does not support that yet. It is also distributed as an AAR, which Eclipse does not support. There are [recipes for converting AARs into Eclipse-friendly Android library projects](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/03/consuming-aars-eclipse.html) that you can try. Otherwise, you will need to reorganize the project code yourself to support the classic Eclipse-style project structure. Mostly, that will involve moving the contents of `library/src/main/` into a regular Eclipse Android library project:

- The `res/` directory and `AndroidManifest.xml` file would go in the library project root directory
- The `java/` directory would be renamed `src/` and also go in the library project directory

However, you will have to repeat this process each and every time the library's author updates the library, at least for those updates that you are interested in.

You may wish to see if there is an alternative library that meets your needs but is better packaged for use with Eclipse.